# Minimum energy of system of identical particles in a 3D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions

Suppose there are 20 electrons in a 3D cubical box with infinite potential at the boundaries. I was trying to calculate the minimum energy of the system under two cases:

1. Assuming they are indistinguishable: This I think is straight forward, I just have to look for degeneracy in values of $n^{2}=n_{x}^{2}+n_{y}^{2}+n_{z}^{2}$. 
   I am however not sure if there can be two electrons in the same $n^{2}$ state [I mean, do I have two consider the two possible spins corresponding to each $n$?]
2. Assuming they are distinguishable particles: I am not sure how this case is different from the first case. How do I solve this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the reason for not putting them all in the lowest state?

Comment: They are fermions, no two fermions can have same state.

Comment: So why is part 2 a problem?